# Image stretches screen instead of fitting within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a page that fits on a single screen without any scrolling, but the CSS that defines its format that I've got isn't working.

The problem can be seen in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcnn1d81/)

The footer is fixed at the bottom of the screen (as it should be), but the background image (within content) extends from below the header to **below** the footer.

There also seems to be a problem with the background image when resizing the browser, but I'm sure that will be fixed when solving this problem.

I have the following code:

**HTML: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function diff(A, B) {
            return A.filter(function (a) {
                return B.indexOf(a) == -1;
            });
        }

        function show(shown) {
            var all = ['home', 'about', 'projects', 'contact'];
            var hide_these = diff(all, shown);
            var hidden;
            document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
            for(hidden in hide_these)
                document.getElementById(hide_these[hidden]).style.display='none';
            $(".sidebar").slideToggle(600);
            return false;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Home
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Hello from Content!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
               Hello from footer.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="about" style="display:none">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    About
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">                    
                <h1>Hello from Content!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
               Hello from footer.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="projects" style="display:none">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Projects
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Hello from Content!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
               Hello from footer.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contact" style="display:none">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Contact
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">                
                <h1>Hello from Content!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
               Hello from footer.
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('body').addClass('loaded');
            });

            $(".menu-btn").on("click", function(){
                $(".sidebar").slideToggle(600);
            });

            $(".header h1").delay(500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS: main.css**

```
    html,body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: arial;
    }

    html, body, #home{
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    a { 
        color: black;
    }

    a:visited { 
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: black; 
    }


    #home{
        min-height:100%;
        position:absolute;
    }

    #about, #projects, #contact{
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    body .sidebar {
        display:block;
    }

    body.loaded .sidebar {
        display:none;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: black;
        height: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: cursive;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        display:flex; 
        align-items: center; 
        z-index: 1;
        position:relative;
    }

    .menu-btn {
        background-image: url("../images/menu.png");
        height: 48px;
        width: 44px;
        margin-left:50px;
    }


    .header h1 {
        opacity: 0;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        top: 80px;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";       /* IE 8 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
        -moz-opacity: 0.5;          /* Netscape */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;        /* Safari 1.x */
        opacity: 0.5;               /* Good browsers */
    }

    .sidebar li {
        color: black;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;

    }

    .sidebar li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 30px;
        background-color: #9da1a4;
        width: 100px; 
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid silver; 
        border-radius: 5px; 
        display: block;
    }

    .sidebar li a:hover {
        background-color: #ebebeb;
    }

    .content {
        top: -80px; /* Header height */
        bottom: 30px;
        background-image:url("../images/arbor.jpeg");
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .content p {
        padding-top: -10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }

    .footer {
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        padding-top: 10px;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .footer a img {
        position: relative;
        top: -5px;
    }
```

My attempt to fix was setting the `.content` area from height = [30px, -80px] (i.e., from the top of the footer to the bottom of the header).

I'm brand new to CSS, so I'm sure this is very poorly formatted, so sorry in advance.

Thanks everyone,
erip

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/  this should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you properly, you want the footer to line the bottom of your content while making sure to fill the browser, no matter the size. This looks like a job for "relative" positioning! Currently your footer is set to "absolute", which is why it overlaps your background.

here's an updated fiddle with RELATIVE changes: https://jsfiddle.net/mcnn1d81/13/

```
 .footer {
         width:100%;
         height:30px;
         text-align: center;
         color: white;
         background-color: black;
         padding-top: 10px;
         bottom:0;
         left:0;
         position: RELATIVE;
    }
.content {
        top: 0px; /* Header height */
        bottom: 30px;
        background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/3WWnZZj.jpg?1");
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        position:RELATIVE;
    }
```

I hope that helps!

EDIT: Added code to keep the content in the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/mcnn1d81/20/
This a quick, rough edit, and realize that what's written will only adhere to the content you put in it. As soon as you tell the content how big it needs to be you'll cause some wonky things to happen. 
If you want dynamic content (that stretches and fits the screen) you'll have to add some code to the resize function to make sure everything stays the same in the CSS. I'd add more, but I've got other things I need to get to. I hope this pushes you in the right direction!

Comment: This is very close, but I also don't want any scrolling.

Comment: If you want the effect of not having a scroll bar, you'll have to check the window size (windowWidth & windowHeight) (and update it whenever it changes) and then set everything relative to the container it's in to get your desired look. That means NO static values at all. 
I advise against this type of webdesign, since it isn't very friendly to anyone not viewing from a browser, but it's most certainly possible. 

I'll update my post in a second with the changes, also cleaning up your HTML (which has JS in it, for some reason :P)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show everything on a single page without any scrolling then Give `position:fixed` to body. You can see the result here http://jsfiddle.net/mcnn1d81/1/ .

Answer (score 0):

just update your css with this.

```
       html,body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: arial;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .content {
            top: -80px; /* Header height */
            bottom: 30px;
            background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/3WWnZZj.jpg?1");
            background-size: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            padding-top: 80px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

that will fix your issue

you can keep background-size : cover; for .content class. it will best option to set your background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
body
{
   margin:0%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```